# Update Content within Cells in Excel sheets using specific format

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-excel-2016

My excel sheet has columns with value like

```
RootUser*UK\abc.def*def, abc*-*https://website.xyz.com/sites/123*
```

And I want the format to be

```
<Mapping Source="UK\abc.def" Target="i:0#.f|membership|abc.def@uk.xyz.com" />
```

The abc.def, xyz and 123 are generic values that I've mentioned here, I have 3000 such columns with actual values and I have to convert them to the given format.

abc.def is the first name and last name, and all columns have the names populated.

How should I make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work, it's a little convoluted, but basically just uses `MID()` with `SEARCH()` to pull the `UK\abc.def` and `abc.def` out of the original string.

```
="<Mapping Source="""&MID(A1,FIND("*",A1)+1,FIND("*",A1,FIND("*",A1)+1)-FIND("*",A1)-1)&"""& Target=""i:0#.f|membership|"&MID(A1,FIND("\",A1)+1,FIND("*",A1,FIND("*",A1)+1)-FIND("*",A1)-4)&"@uk.xyz.com"" />"
```

Edit: You mention `123` in your OP, but I don't see where it's included in the output, so I didn't do anything special with it.

Edit2: The `|abc.def@uk.xyz.com` can be changed to whatever the `UK\abc.def` bit is (UK or US):

```
="<Mapping Source="""&MID(A1,FIND("*",A1)+1,FIND("*",A1,FIND("*",A1)+1)-FIND("*",A1)-1)&"""& Target=""i:0#.f|membership|"&MID(A1,FIND("\",A1)+1,FIND("*",A1,FIND("*",A1)+1)-FIND("*",A1)-4)&"@"&LEFT(MID(A1,FIND("*",A1)+1,FIND("*",A1,FIND("*",A1)+1)-FIND("*",A1)-1),2)&".xyz.com"" />"
```

Comment: you saved Gotham again. Worked like a charm, I'm gonna shine the Bat signal one more time though, Once I've used the formula and populated the field, it displays the value. Now If I try to copy the cell, it copies the formula and not the value. How do I copy the value instead of the formula.

Comment: Batman I forgot to mention one thing in my OP, there are UK accounts and US accounts as well. There are about 3300 cells and some of them are UK accounts and some are US accounts.... In the end the URL for US accounts should be US.xyz.com as for UK accounts it is UK.xyz.com.  Is it possible to do it in the same formula or do I have to seperate the accounts first.

Comment: @CodeAbaddon - Can you add some more examples to your OP, with their expected outcome? That should be possible.

Comment: @CodeAbaddon - See my edit. Also, if you want to paste just the values (not formula) after you copy, right click to Paste and click "Paste Special" --> "Paste as Values" (the `123` icon)